# How is the return statement working in the following java method?

Tags: java

is it possible by any means in the following method that the print statement get executed after the if statement returns true in the for loop?

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    if(o == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
        if(o.equals(getNodeAt(i).data)){
            System.out.println("contains passed here: "+o+" "+getNodeAt(i)+" "+i);
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println(getNodeAt(1));
    }
    System.out.println("cointain failed here "+o);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What output do you have?

Comment: it is printing "contains passed here: " and then it's executing System.out.println(getNodeAt(1)); cumulatively as for loop progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course; call the method again. More effectively, efficiently, and specifically with an `Object` such that `o.equals(getNodeAt(i).data` is `false`. The truth is...

"[B]y any means" is a pretty loose constraint; you say...

**is it possible by any means** in the following method that the print statement get[s] executed **after the if statement returns true in the for loop**?

*I'm saying* that YES, that's possible by any means when the means are recalling the method. In fact, it's perpetually true as long as you're using whatever container.

---

**Proof:**

Assume that it is impossible by any means in the following method that the second return statement gets executed after the if statement returns true in the for loop.

```
static String proof(Object o) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
            if (o == null) {
                return "I'm returning from the for loop!!!";
            }
        }
        return "I'm now called after the for's return statement (by any means)!! - QED";
}
```

But given...

```
public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.println(proof(null));
        System.out.println(proof(new String("Hello Proof!")));
}// end main method
```

the ouput is...

```
I'm returning from the for loop!!!
I'm now called after the for's return statement!! - QED
```

Therefore our assumption is wrong and it is possible by *some* means for the second return statement to get executed after the if statement returns true in the for loop.

;)

---

A "better" way to phrase that so it's clear what you're asking would be, perhaps, - "Is it possible for the code in a method body to *continue* to execute after a return statement?"

That answer is no and can be tested in any good IDE as follows.

```
static String proof(Object o) {
        for(;;)
            if(true)
                return "Donkey Butts";
        return "Poops";
}
```

This basically says forever it is true that I will return "Donkey Butts". In any IDE I'd waste my time using you will get an error for "unreachable statement". The IDE can determine this truth from your code which implicitly is telling you that any time the loop is active and the `if` is `true` the code below cannot execute.

Comment: after the if statement returns true in the for loop?

Comment: Yep, it will return then you call it again....The point here is basically you gave a restriction that isn't a restriction. By any means necessary. If I want it to print after it returns, hell, I'll just try again. If you want something specific then ask up front so it's clear. @Gajjan

Comment: I asked very specifically if it prints AFTER the return statement returns true in the for loop.

Comment: It's hard to find humor in an answer when you are struggling with something for quite some time. But thanks it did help.

Comment: @Gajjan, I understand. That's why I made the edits. You could cut straight to it by saying the `return` statement *immediately* returns. If it couldn't be depended on, the world would be horrible.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is definitely not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, but it is possible that System.out isn't flushed until after the return statement.

Comment: Umm... yeah, but it would be quite unusual.

Comment: "is it possible by any means"

Comment: Yeah, sure, it's just rare enough I've never seen it happening. But I'd rather debug the code and make sure the return statement is really executed before.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski - if it is printing "contains passed here: " that means it is executing return statement right? Supposedly? :-/

Answer (score 1):

Nothing inside a method can be executed after the return statement.

But when you deal with output operations, things can happen quite differently from what you might expect. In fact, writes to an output file/device are often buffered, i.e. written to an internal array. When the array is full, it is sent to the file/device. This happens for efficiency reasons, because writing a few big chunks of data is faster than writing lots of small ones.

This means that these operations sometimes seem to happen long after the place where they appear in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you enclose in a try and finally.

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    if(o == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
        try {
            if(o.equals(getNodeAt(i).data)){
                System.out.println("contains passed here: "+o+" "+getNodeAt(i)+" "+i);
                return true;
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println(getNodeAt(1));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("cointain failed here "+o);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: no I am just trying to make sure when exactly the if statement is  being executed and when it's not.